# Firebase Auth with email for Flutter

Tags: email, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I'm currently struggling to implement email sign up and log in in my app. I can't use google sign-in or other alternative methods for business reasons.

How to implement Firebase Authentication with Email in Flutter? Is there a way to do it with the Firebase Auth plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' show FirebaseAuth;

...
final firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I know the general direction

Comment: What about password less login in flutter

Comment: @asifa can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth . How to implement this in flutter

Comment: I think it's better to create a new question. I haven't looked into that one myself yet.

Comment: Is it possible to do in flutter. I am currently not allowed to post new questions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I haven't tried or investigated.